System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libdl' or one of its dependencies
im use .net 8 with mongodb and mongoClient base on microservice
getting eror like :
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libdl' or one of its dependencies In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you're using glibc, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable:  2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/runtimes/linux-x64/native/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/runtimes/linux/native/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.4/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/runtimes/linux-x64/native/liblibdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/runtimes/linux/native/liblibdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.4/liblibdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/liblibdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/runtimes/linux-x64/native/libdl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/runtimes/linux/native/libdl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.4/libdl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/libdl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/runtimes/linux-x64/native/liblibdl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/runtimes/linux/native/liblibdl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.4/liblibdl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27 /app/bin/Debug/net8.0/liblibdl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-04-26 13:37:27  2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.LibraryLoader.LinuxLibrary.dlopen(String filename, Int32 flags) 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.LibraryLoader.LinuxLibrary..ctor(String path) 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.LibraryLoader..ctor() 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.Library.<>c.<.cctor>b__0_65() 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at System.Lazy1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
2024-04-26 13:37:27    at System.Lazy1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor) 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at System.Lazy1.CreateValue()
2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.Library.<>c.<.cctor>b__0_1()
2024-04-26 13:37:27    at System.Lazy1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at System.Lazy1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
2024-04-26 13:37:27    at System.Lazy1.CreateValue() 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.Library.get_mongocrypt_new() 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.CryptClientFactory.Create(CryptOptions options) 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.CryptClientCreator.CreateCryptClient(CryptOptions options) 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.CryptClientCreator.CreateCryptClient(CryptClientSettings cryptClientSettings) 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.Initialize() 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.MultiServerCluster.Initialize() 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Driver.ClusterRegistry.CreateCluster(ClusterKey clusterKey) 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Driver.ClusterRegistry.GetOrCreateCluster(ClusterKey clusterKey) 2024-04-26 13:37:27    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor(MongoClientSettings settings)
docker file
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y  libc6-dev
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj", "src/Services/Identity/Identity.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Services/Identity/Identity.API"
RUN dotnet build "Identity.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Identity.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Identity.API.dll"]
